# jquery revert time left to time spend .setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a timer running and when it finishes I pass the `var seconds` into a function.
I need to convert this timer from seconds left to the time spent until the call.

Now it says "You click all div's in 16 seconds", but the 16 seconds is the time left.

Is this possible or do I have to build an another function to handle this?

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you started a countdown of 30s and you know that 16s have already passed, then the time elapsed is 30s - 16s = 14s

```
function win() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('#panel').hide();
    var timeElapsed = 30 - seconds;
    $('#won').fadeIn('slow').html('<span class="">You click all div\'s in ' + timeElapsed + ' seconds</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a seperate `score` variable that counts seconds up as `seconds` counts down.

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/12/

Or, a better way is to just subtract the starting time (30s) and the elapsed time (`seconds`).

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/13/